# xcode - tree conflict on Pull after pods Update

Tags: xcode, git

After a pods Updates, both in the remote and the local version, I am trying to make a PULL with unlucky. Xcode code say:

The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts. The files "a large listo o file" had a tree conflict.

How could resolve that conflicts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using `SVN` can also cause this problem.

I resolved this problem by deleting the file in finder that Xcode tipped. But the next time I update the project (all of your project files) the tip will show again. So it may be not the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, deleting the pods folder before pulling again fixed it.